# Object created while using String methods in java

Tags: java, string, object

```
   public class StringDemo
   {  
     public static void main(String [] args)
      {  
        String s = "Sachin"; 
        s.concat(" Tendulkar"); 
        s.toLowerCase();  
        System.out.print(s);  
     } 
  }
```

This example giving output as : Sachin

then how many objects have been created?

Comment: every string method that returns a modified string creates at least one new object.

Comment: *"This example giving output as : Java"* ... really?

Comment: Java Strings are immutable. So it should print **Sachin** not **Java**. And there are 3 String objects created in your program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: an indeterminate number.

- on the face of it, the two operations on `s` each create a single String object,
- two more String objects are created at load time to represent the literals,
- objects may be created when `print` is called: internally to the `System.out` PrintWriter and the stream stack that it wraps,
- each String object *may* (or may not) have a distinct `char[]` object inside it,
- it is possible that the operations on `s` could be optimized away, since they actually have no effect on the output of the program (!!),
- when the application is called, it will be passed a String[] argument, potentially populated with multiple String, and (finally),
- an arbitrary number of objects will be created during JVM bootstrapping and class loading ... prior to the application starting.

So, depending on what objects you count, how you count them, and the other assumptions that you make, the answer could be some number from zero to a very large number of objects.

Note: the normal *quiz* answer for this would be "2 Strings are created", but as you can see the answer is a lot more complicated than that.

Note 2: the `concat` and `toLowerCase` methods do NOT create strings in the string pool.  In fact, the only String operation that puts strings into the pool is `intern`.  (It is easy to verify this experimentally, or by reading the Java class library source code.)

Answer (score 3):

`String` in java is a immutable type.

```
 s.concat(" Tendulkar"); 
 s.toLowerCase();
```

these 2 lines return 2 distinct strings and doesn't affect the original string.

Comment: so its creating only one object right?

Comment: @Ramanlfc Let's don't forget that the literal `" Tendulkar"` is an object itself :P.

Comment: @AvinashJadhav as Tom brought to my attention ,you actually have 4 string objects

Comment: And each String object could actually comprise 2 separate objects; i.e. each String has an internal `char[]`.  Then there is the issue of *when* the objects are created ...

Answer (score 1):

In java `String` is considered as immutable which means that it cannot be changed once its created, so if you count how many you have, on the first line you declared the first one, when you did `s.concat("SE 6")` you created a new object, and finally `s.toLowerCase()` created the 3rd object, therefore 3 string objects are created.